Solve the differential equation over a rectangle

Solve the following differential equation $$y'=2x^2+3y^2$$
over the rectangle $|x|\le1$ and $|y-1|\le1$ and where $y(0)=1$.

What is this thing? I have never ever encountered questions like these. What does it mean by saying "over a rectangle"? I tried to solve the ODE nonetheless, but wasn't able to do so.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

According to MathWorld, this is a Riccati differential equation that is not solvable using only algebraic, exponential, and logarithmic functions. Wolfram Alpha gives a solution in terms of Bessel functions of the first kind.

Solving "over the rectangle" just means you're asked to find a solution that exists in the region $[-1, 1] \times [0, 2]$. This is more common in partial differential equations where that rectangle would be the domain of the inputs and the range would be something like the real numbers.
